# How do I arrange the text in my code to look like the attached image?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, margin

I want the picture to look like this:

[image]

but, it looks like this:

[image]

My code is this:

```html
<div className="card">
  <img src="html-css-assessment/images/desert.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%" style="height:194px">
    <div className="container">
      <header>
        <img src="person-avatar.jpg" id="avatar">
          <div>
            <h3 style="color:#000" className="title1">Title goes here</h3>
            <p style="color:#232F34">Secondary text</p>
          </div>
      </header>
      <div>
        <body font-size="22px" className="body1">
        Greyhound divisely hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.
        </body>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Write your problem clearly!

Comment: looking at your code overall and especially how you used the header and body tag, I suggest you to read mdn docs or simply copy a codepen card that matches the design.